# Monero original giving me this strange line saying upgrade

Tags: monerod, monero-forks, monero-original

```
2018-05-30 23:58:37.090 [P2P7]  WARN    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:272     [1;31m[211.20.7.199:64432 INC]  peer claims higher version that we think - we may be forked from the network and a software upgrade may be needed[0m
```

So I have been using Monero original for a little while, and now I have noticed that a strange line saying we may be forked from the network etc etc etc.

I am wondering if that is going to cause issues for my node and wallet?

Answer (score 2):

Monero has updated its consensus rules a couple months ago. What some call "Monero original" is just an old Monero version on which some people continued to mine. You need to update your software so it can parse the new blocks/transactions or it will stay on the old chain. Until you do, it will not be able to understand those "new version" blocks, and warn about them.

Answer (score 1):

This is the support page and forum for Monero (XMR), not Monero Original (XMO). We will not likely have the information that you are looking for.

Comment: Cryptonote projects are covered by this SE (https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9/).